# How to get "-property foo.insidefoo" to work in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Anyone know the proper way to do this statement?

```
$dlls | format-list -Property name, Versioninfo.Product
```

When I use the dot variable with `-Property`, it just generates a new property instead of giving me Product.

What I'm trying to do is get the source of whole lists of DLLs to see where they came from (e.g. Microsoft, Google, Company, etc ). If there is an easier way to do this, please tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that format. You can provide `Format-List` a `[hashtable]` that defines a new property name and an expression to generate the value though:

```
$newCol = @{
    Name = 'Product'
    Expression = {
        $_.Versioninfo.Product
    }
}
$dlls | format-list -Property name,$newCol
```

Comment: I ultimately opted to generate CSVs which actually works better for my application. However, your answer works great for this question. I really should get used to hash-tables in PS. sigh...